# HttpPostedFile (XML) contents to List<T> C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an XML file I created with Linq which now I want to be able to import back into my Umbraco test site. I have tried many suggestions online but first here is an example of my class:

[pastebin example of Import Class](http://pastebin.com/rwYyWnL7)

In this class I'm using the XmlDeserialize method, however because my file was created with Linq (I presume this is the reason, I may be wrong), I get the following error:

`{"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."}`

looking further into the error I see where the issue is:

`{"<BlogPosts xmlns=''> was not expected."}`

I believe this is happening because of how I'm writing the file using Linq [here](http://pastebin.com/6rGNdwgN)

You can see I'm not setting the namespace when creating the file.

My issue is that when I try to use the Linq methods I don't get much further but I get different errors.

here are what I have tried and the errors I got:

```
string myFileNew = myFile.ToString();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myFileNew);
List<BlogPosts> blogPosts = doc.Descendants("Field").ToList();
```

The error:

```
CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UmbracoBlogsExportPackage.Models.BlogPosts>'
```

The next thing I tried was this:

```
string myFileNew = myFile.ToString();
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(myFileNew);
                BlogPosts objBlogPosts = new BlogPosts();
                List<BlogPosts> lstblogs
                    = (from _blog in xdoc1.Element("BlogPosts").Elements("blog")
                       select new BlogPosts
                       {
                           Title = _blog.Element("Title").Value,
                           BodyText = _blog.Element("BodyText").Value,
                           PublishDate = _blog.Element("PublishDate").Value,
                           Author = _blog.Element("Author").Value
                       }).ToList();
```

To which I got this error:

```
{"Could not find file 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper'.":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper"}
```

So I moved onto try this:

```
 string myFileNew = myFile.ToString();
 XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(myFileNew
                var blogPosts = xmlDoc.Descendants("BlogPosts").Select(Blog => new BlogPosts
                {
                    Title = Blog.Element("Title").Value,
                    BodyText = Blog.Element("BodyText").Value,
                    PublishDate = BlogElement("PublishDate").Value,
                    Author = Blog.Element("Author").Value

                }));
                blogPosts.ToList();
```

for which I got this error:

```
CS1026: ) expected
```

on the line with: `XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(myFileNew`

Oh also here is my model class:
[pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/dK9LF01h)

What I am asking is can anyone give me a point in the right direction for what I should be doing? Because I'm exhausting all the possibilities I can find online and I am obviously doing something wrong.

My [Export Class](http://pastebin.com/DzLuF2Ld) returns this Xml file

```
<BlogPosts>
  <Blog>
    <Title>یہ ایک بلاگ پوسٹ ہے</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;یہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہے&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;یہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہے&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;یہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہےیہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہےیہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہے&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;یہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہے&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;یہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہےیہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہے&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;یہ کچھ بے ترتیب بلاگ مواد ہے&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>29/09/2016 15:49:47</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/1006/6882554979_e7386292ce_b.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
  <Blog>
    <Title>זהו פוסט בבלוג</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;זהו חלק מתכני בלוג אקראיים!&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>17/03/2017 14:20:03</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/1001/black-snow.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
  <Blog>
    <Title>وهذا هو بلوق وظيفة جديدة</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;هذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديد&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;هذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديد&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;هذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديدهذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديدهذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديدهذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديدهذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديدهذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديد&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;هذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديد&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;هذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديدهذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديد&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;هذه هي بعض محتوى بلوق جديد&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>12/05/2016 14:57:45</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/1005/6882554979_e7386292ce_b.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
  <Blog>
    <Title>The 10 remarkable features of object</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;Ita prorsus, inquam; Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Ergo adhuc, quantum equidem intellego, causa non videtur fuisse mutandi nominis. Quia dolori non voluptas contraria est, sed doloris privatio. Nos autem non solum beatae vitae istam esse oblectationem videmus, sed etiam levamentum miseriarum. Quodsi ipsam honestatem undique pertectam atque absolutam. Nos cum te, M. Quod vestri non item.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Cum id quoque, ut cupiebat, audivisset, evelli iussit eam, qua erat transfixus, hastam. Quarum ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur. Quid iudicant sensus? Quo tandem modo?&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>12/05/2016 14:35:45</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/1002/black-snow.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
  <Blog>
    <Title>You really need to read this!</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Ut aliquid scire se gaudeant? Hanc ergo intuens debet institutum illud quasi signum absolvere. Vestri haec verecundius, illi fortasse constantius. Itaque sensibus rationem adiunxit et ratione effecta sensus non reliquit. Sed ea mala virtuti magnitudine obruebantur. Quasi ego id curem, quid ille aiat aut neget. Verum tamen cum de rebus grandioribus dicas, ipsae res verba rapiunt; Apparet statim, quae sint officia, quae actiones.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;Virtutibus igitur rectissime mihi videris et ad consuetudinem nostrae orationis vitia posuisse contraria. Nonne videmus quanta perturbatio rerum omnium consequatur, quanta confusio? Sed eum qui audiebant, quoad poterant, defendebant sententiam suam. Ut necesse sit omnium rerum, quae natura vigeant, similem esse finem, non eundem.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>12/05/2016 14:36:00</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/1004/6882554979_e7386292ce_b.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
  <Blog>
    <Title>This is a wonderful news item</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Commoda autem et incommoda in eo genere sunt, quae praeposita et reiecta diximus; Bestiarum vero nullum iudicium puto. Est enim effectrix multarum et magnarum voluptatum. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur. Quarum ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur. Sed virtutem ipsam inchoavit, nihil amplius.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Ita redarguitur ipse a sese, convincunturque scripta eius probitate ipsius ac moribus. Istam voluptatem, inquit, Epicurus ignorat? Sed venio ad inconstantiae crimen, ne saepius dicas me aberrare; Sic, et quidem diligentius saepiusque ista loquemur inter nos agemusque communiter. Primum in nostrane potestate est, quid meminerimus? Consequens enim est et post oritur, ut dixi. Hoc mihi cum tuo fratre convenit. Immo videri fortasse. Itaque in rebus minime obscuris non multus est apud eos disserendi labor. Aliud igitur esse censet gaudere, aliud non dolere.&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>12/05/2016 14:35:54</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/1003/black-snow.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
  <Blog>
    <Title>Txt Starter Kit For Umbraco Released</Title>
    <BodyText>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;Sed ad haec, nisi molestum est, habeo quae velim. Neque enim disputari sine reprehensione nec cum iracundia aut pertinacia recte disputari potest. Nec vero alia sunt quaerenda contra Carneadeam illam sententiam. Deinde disputat, quod cuiusque generis animantium statui deceat extremum. Facit igitur Lucius noster prudenter, qui audire de summo bono potissimum velit; Quis non odit sordidos, vanos, leves, futtiles?&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;Negat enim summo bono afferre incrementum diem. Haec mihi videtur delicatior, ut ita dicam, molliorque ratio, quam virtutis vis gravitasque postulat. Haec quo modo conveniant, non sane intellego. Quis enim confidit semper sibi illud stabile et firmum permansurum, quod fragile et caducum sit? Multoque hoc melius nos veriusque quam Stoici. Igitur neque stultorum quisquam beatus neque sapientium non beatus. De hominibus dici non necesse est. Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Nobis Heracleotes ille Dionysius flagitiose descivisse videtur a Stoicis propter oculorum dolorem. At, illa, ut vobis placet, partem quandam tuetur, reliquam deserit.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</BodyText>
    <PublishDate>20/09/2021 00:00:00</PublishDate>
    <Author>0</Author>
    <Image>/media/SampleImages/1077/pic05.jpg</Image>
    <Comments />
  </Blog>
</BlogPosts>
```

## Please Note

I am not asking you to debug my entire project, as the export controller is working fine, I just need a point in the right direction for the import, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as these are all example code I got online which I contextualized to fit my project

All pastebin links included are to give you an idea of where all the data is being pulled from and pushed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFile` is `HttpPostedFileBase`, and calling `ToString()` on it produces nothing of value.

What you could be doing is this:

```
var file = myContext.Result.Request.Files["file"];

var xdocument = XDocument.Load(file.InputStream);
```

And then proceed with your XLINQ-based parsing logic.

Comment: Maybe you mean : `var xdocument = XDocument.Load(file.InputStream);`

Comment: @har07 Spot on! Thanks.